# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when publishing a sql project VS 2013

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2013, sql-data-tools

When I try to publish a SQL Project to a database (SQL server 2008 r2) from Visual Studio 2013, I get a dialog box saying

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

and then the publish never finishes (the progress icon keeps spinning).

[image: VS 2013 error message]

When I click in the "Output" tab, I don't see any errors there. It says:

```
========== Build: 4 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========.
```

When I do a "Schema Compare" from VS 2013 between my project and the production database, I get the same error.

Is there any way to track down how and why VS2013's Data Tools Operations is producing that error?

Comment: Attach a debugger to vS and set Break on All Exceptions.

Comment: I tried: 1. Uncheck "My Code" in debug options, then 2. Attach the debugger to the devenv process then 3. tried the publish but it did not break on the exception. It just showed the pop dialog with the error as before.

Comment: Debug, Exceptions, check Break on all CLR Exceptions.

Comment: I couldn't get VS to break on the exception. I checked all exception types.

Comment: My `.refactorlog` file was causing this. I didn't need it so I just deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem again. My problem was that the definition of one of my table-valued functions in the server (the target server of the publish) had a SQLCmd parameter commented out:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyProblematicFunc
(   
    @beg_date date,
    @end_date date
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT  
        Name,
        Address,
        --,cast([$(DBreferenceFromVS)].[dbo].[ConvertNumToDate](NumericDate) as DATE) [Create Date] 
        -- ^^^^ This comment above was causing the error on publish and on schema comparison. I had to remove it in the server
    FROM  RandomTable
```